# Disable SK1 and SK2 on Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile-6.5

I am wanting to disable the softkey1 and softkey2 on Windows Mobile 6.5.  Below are the registries:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Today\Keys\112]

@=""

Open=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Today\Keys\113]

@=""

Open=""

When I assign both values to empty for \Keys\112 and \Keys\113, it will use the default softkey values.  But when i assign each value to a white space, the labels for softkey1 and softkey2 are gone which is fine, but when i click on the positions where softkey1 and softkey2 were at, a pop up message says error since it can not find the handling application for that key. Wondering if i can disable them?

thanks.

Comment: whoever votes down on this question, better give me some explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You should not handle the registry for softkeys that way. Better give them meaning full values.

If you like to get a kiosk mode device, assign the keys to the kiosk app or a locked down program starter.

You should not wonder that the OS behaves strange, when you assign unsupported values to registry keys.

As far as I know there is no way to disable the softkeys on the home screen. But you can subclass the menubar and reject 'mouse' clicks at there locations.Be aware, that pressing the F1 and F2 hardware keys will still fire the softkey assigned function.So you have to capture and reject F1 and F2 key messages too.

I have a lot of informations about kiosk mode apps on my homepage.